# Number of Sequences Formed from n Letters (with repetition)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> You have n  tiles, where each tile has one letter printed on it.
>
> Return the number of possible non-empty sequences of letters you can
> make using the letters printed on those tiles.
>
> For example, "AAB" results in 8 sequences: "A", "B", "AA", "AB", "BA",
> "AAB", "ABA", "BAA"

According to me, the number of sequences should be obtained by the following expression:

```
(nP1+nP2+...nPn)/(frequency_1! x frequency_2! ...)
```

which, for the above example would be:

(3P1+3P2+3P3)/(2! x 1!) which is the incorrect answer.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: This is a more difficult problem than you realize.  It would be better to count the 1-letter separately from the 2-letter, and the 3-letter, etc... and add the results together.  You can count the $k$-letter words by way of the linked post.

Comment: As for why your answer is incorrect, the division by your `frequency_k!`'s would have been justified by way of the shepherd's principle... that if when counting a scenario you overcounted *every* case the same number of times you can correct your count by dividing by the number of times you counted each.  Here, that did not work.  Yes, we counted "$A$" twice (*once as "$A_1$" and again as "$A_2$"*) just as we counted each of the others here twice ("$A_1A_2$" vs "$A_2A_1$") but we did not count "$B$" twice... we only counted it once, so shepherd's principle does not apply.